# I can't install tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow, installation, zsh, tensorflow2.0

I wanna install tensorflow2.0, but it just failed.
According to error, it said, zsh: 2.0.0-beta1 not found.

```py
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

```py
zsh: 2.0.0-beta1 not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hypen `-`

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0beta1
```

Answer (score 0):

First,Download tensorflow package ,this is the version of tensorflow about 2.1rc in Windows,you can download by url(https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/44/a88475dc6905a9816227bff0f31355f7072efa119faff336aa18b27a3347/tensorflow-2.1.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl), other version and platform(https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0rc2/#files),  finally,you can use pip command to install(pip install tensorflow****).